# cannot read property "toFixed" of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have the following block of code:

```
export interface Record {
Percentage_Emissions: number;
Percentage_Emissions_Previous: number;
Vs_Previous_Year: number;
}

const Info = ({
  data
}: {
  data: dashboard.Results<Record>;
}) => {
  const styles = Styles(myStyles);
  const record = data.results.records[0];
  let redStyle =
  record.Percentage_Emissions < 0
    ? [styles.textInRed]
    : [styles.textInGreen];
    const percentageText =
    record.Percentage_Emissions === undefined
      ? `-`
      : `${(
          record.Percentage_
Emissions * 100
        ).toFixed(2)}${strings("data.percent")}`;
```

I just realised that the problem is with the render method, which calls:

```
 <Text
          style={[styles.text, styles.textLarge]}
        >{`${record.Percentage_Emissions.toFixed(2)}${strings(
          "data.percent"
        )}`}</Text>
```

I think the problem is that the render method assumes that Percentage_Emissions is defined, but I still don't know how to fix it.

In the emulator, the page crashes because of the error "Cannot read property "toFixed" of undefined. it is supposed to return a dash if no data was found, or else return the rounded information if it is available with conditional formatting. I can't see what is wrong with my code. Does anyone have any ideas on what is happening here?

Comment: Does ```record.Emissions``` exist in record object?

Comment: is that `Percentage_Emissions` for `Emissions` in `record.Emissions * 100` ??

Comment: Sorry it is supposed to be Percentage Emissions. I have just corrected it to Percentage_Emissions but the same error occurs. And yes record.Percentage_Emissions is in the object.

Comment: please update what is in `record` for more clarity

Comment: Okay I updated the record

Comment: my bad ... I'm expecting about this record `const record = data.results.records[0];`

Comment: Try logging `record.Percentage_Emissions` directly to see what it has?

Comment: consider assigning a local short variable to `record.Percentage_Emissions` to make your code more readable (and less typo-prone)

Comment: and also create a separate utility function to return a (valid) number in percentage format, that can then be tested independently of your record structure.

Comment: Just add a default number value to it, if it's value is undefined
`${(record.Percentage_Emissions || 0).toFixed(2)}`

Comment: Just to clarify, do you men in the render method or in the definition above?

Comment: It's still confusing. Can you please post full code with complete render function and definition?

Answer (score 0):

Split your problem up:

```
const percentAsString = (n) => (n * 100).toFixed(2) + strings('data.percent');

const safePercentAsString = (n) => (n === undefined) ? '-' : percentAsString(n);
```

These are trivially unit testable.

Then within your own function, just do:

```
const percentageText = safePercentAsString(record.Percentage_Emissions);
```

If you still have problems with the output, you known the problem must lay in the handling of the `record` object, and not your output code.